# Is there a way to send a message to Amazon SQS 'without' using AWS Credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

My application requires to send message to the sqs queue. I am able to do the required with an ease using `boto.sqs.connect_to_region()` from http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/sqs_tut.html . The idea is very neat and simple [No questions here]

Lately I realized that a need arises to send the data without using the AWS password. I want to know how to send data to AWS SQS without providing and credentials.

I also read about : https://github.com/chilts/awssum/issues/48

Can someone point me on how to perform a simple push to SQS with no creds. Lately I think the answer can be around IAM role(some policy related or role) or SQS queue creation.

Help a bro out mates :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is using IAM roles. Where are you running your Python boto script from? An EC2? AWS Lambda with Python?

You can learn a little about using roles to get credentials here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk-ec2-instances

You will have to create an IAM Policy that has the permissions to execute what you need to do with SQS. Examples:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSExamples.html).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Queue1_Policy_UUID",
    "Statement": 
    {
        "Sid":"Queue1_Send_Receive",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "111122223333"
        },
        "Action": ["sqs:SendMessage","sqs:ReceiveMessage"],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:444455556666:queue1"
    }
}
```

And you will attach the policy you create to your Role. You will then assign your role to the EC2 you are running your script on, so when it runs, the EC2 instance will generate temporary credentials based on its role.